# Yarn install a single package to single workspace

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

This is my project set up

```
proj:
  package.json - workspaces["app/frontend", "app/backend"]
  app
    frontend - package.json
    backend - package.json
```

say I cd to `proj`

I want to do  `yarn workspace app/frontend add uuid -dev` (add a pkg to one of the workspace)

err is `Unknown workspace "app/frontend"`, wonder what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`yarn workspace frontend add uuid --save-dev`

Answer (score 1):

When you define your workspaces in the `package.json` you should use relative path to the workspace:

```
"workspaces": [
  "app/frontent",
  "app/backend"
]
```

However, when you refer to your workspace in `yarn workspace ...` command you should use the package name of this workspace (including namespace).

For example, if your `frontend/package.json` defines

```
{
  name: "@myproj/frontend".
  ...
}
```

you will use

```
yarn workspace @myproj/frontent add uuid --save-dev
```